# Excel event listener in C++

Tags: c++, excel, events, listener

I want to write an event listener in C++ for MS Excel (2007/2010), and I am looking for resources that can get me started, preferably a working code sample.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried nothing. If you know how to do that please share a code, if no, please pass by.

Comment: This site isn't really a site to ask people to write code for you. That is why I asked. And now I am passing.

Comment: You should read more carefully. I did not ask some one to Write code for me. I asked to provide, share , copy/paste a code sample. I'm not asking some one to do my job. My assumption is that among all those coders who read this site from time to time could be some one who resolved the problem like that or similar and he would kindly copy/paste a code which I could start my investigations from. I am really sorry if my intentions are not obvious.

Comment: Bottom line: Your question was a bit lazy. Put more effort into your questions, and you shall receive more answers. That is all.

Comment: It is too early to bottom line this question because given example gives compile errors. Also I did not get the point why my initial question was edited (rephrased)?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft Support has a HOWTO called "[Handle Events for Excel by Using Visual C++ .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/309301)". The example code there is fairly long, so I don't want to paste any of it here. Ask new questions if you find any of it confusing.

Comment: Given example does not compile correctly as gives hundreds of errors in excel.tlh

Comment: I found the following example more effective: http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/3206013/Re-Cell-change-event-in-Excel.aspx